# could not copy the folder with .txt file in it to another folder

Tags: command-line

I'm just trying to copy the folder present in `/home/black/Desktop/linux`   to another folder present in `/home/black/Desktop/ubuntu`

now what i did.`cd /home/black/Desktop/linux` now am there in linux folder in Desktop.
Then:

```
 cp -r linux/ /home/black/Desktop/ubuntu
 no such file or directory
```

Between when i am copying the content from linux folder like .txt file to another directory i can do that smoothly. so y use -r when copying folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cp -r /home/black/Desktop/linux /home/black/Desktop/ubuntu
```

If there is a specific folder in the `linux` folder, you will need to add that folder to the source path. The source and destination paths need to be separated by a space. Your original command likely failed because you you used a source path of `linux/` and the trailing `/` leaves an undefined path in the command. Using the `-r` invokes recursive copying to copy all the contents of the directory.

Comment: thnx man. so for copying i dont need to goto in that directory from where it will copy?

Comment: Copying can take place from whatever directory you are currently working in - you just have to use absolute file paths. You can copy using relative file paths only when the copying is taking place in the same current working directory in your shell.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
cp -Ri ~/Desktop/linux ~/Desktop/ubuntu
```

Comment: thank you it also worked. figured out ~ but what is -Ri

Comment: if you do like this,linux folder won't delete.

Comment: try this command `cp --help`,see the meaning for R and i.

Comment: ok. ty so much. +1 vote for you after 15rep :D

Comment: if you doesn't want linux folder in the desktop and moving the linux folder into the ubuntu folder then run this command `mv -i ~/Desktop/linux ~/Desktop/ubuntu`

Answer (score 1):

I prefer copying with this format: `cp [OPTION]... -t TARGET_FOLDER SOURCE_FILE_OR_FOLDERS...`

e.g.1 Copying a single directory/folder:

```
cp -rv -t /home/black/Desktop/ubuntu /home/black/Desktop/linux
```

e.g.2 Copying multiple directories:

```
cp -rv -t /home/black/Desktop/ubuntu /home/black/Desktop/linux /home/black/Desktop/someOtherFileOrFolder
```

e.g.3 Copying multiple directories and files:

```
cp -rv -t /home/black/Desktop/ubuntu /home/black/Desktop/linux /home/black/Desktop/someOtherFileOrFolder /home/black/Documents/myFile.txt
```

e.g.4 Copying multiple directories and files:

```
cp -ruv -t /home/black/Desktop/ubuntu /home/black/Desktop/linux /home/black/Desktop/someOtherFileOrFolder /home/black/Documents/myFile.txt
```

with parameters `r` and `t` for recursive and verbosity options.

---

A little about the switches:

`-r` for recursive copy (copy folder all contents including sub-directory structure and contents)

`-u` copy  only  when  the  SOURCE file is newer than the destination file or when the destination file is missing

`-v` outputs the copy operations performed.

Comment: oh.. cool edit ty man.

Comment: i use this very often to backup my files to external HDD... and for backup operations one more switch _-u_ (_--update_) is really good one for me... :)